# Getting InvalidRecordException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

In my application, I get data which gets queued using kafka and saved on the disk and the consumer which gets this data from kafka and does the processing. But When my consumer is trying to read data from kafka I am getting below exceptions :

```
2017-06-09 10:57:24,733 ERROR NetworkClient Uncaught error in request completion:
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TcpMessage-1 at offset 155884487
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:628) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.handleFetchResponse(Fetcher.java:566) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$000(Fetcher.java:69) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1.onSuccess(Fetcher.java:139) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$1.onSuccess(Fetcher.java:136) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:908) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:853) [kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
at com.affirmed.mediation.edr.kafka.tcpMessage.TcpMessageConsumer.doWork(TcpMessageConsumer.java:190) [EdrServer.jar:?]
at com.affirmed.mediation.edr.kafka.tcpMessage.TcpMessageConsumer.run(TcpMessageConsumer.java:248) [EdrServer.jar:?]

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException: Record is corrupt (stored crc = 2016852547, computed crc = 1399853379)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.Record.ensureValid(Record.java:226) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]***
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:617) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar:?]
... 15 more
```

Could anyone please help me with this. I got stuck with it and not able to figure out the root.

Comment: I have a similar issues and getting "org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Uncaught error in request completion:

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Error deserializing key/value for partition"

I have simple java consumer which works fine but the spring boot service throws this error.
It looks like the version issue, I will update if figure out the correct match.

kafka client version - 0.9.0.1
Spring Kafka version - 1.0.6.RELEASE
SpringBoot version - 1.5.9.RELEASE

I can't change kafka client version but can change other versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got stuck with it and not able to figure out the root.

The stack trace already tells you what the exact problem is:

```
2017-06-09 10:57:24,733 ERROR NetworkClient Uncaught error in request completion:
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TcpMessage-1 at offset 155884487
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException: Record is corrupt (stored crc = 2016852547, computed crc = 1399853379)
```

The root problem is that there is corrupted data for message offset 155884487 in partition 1 of your input topic `TcpMessage`.  This indicates that there is a problem with the local storage of the Kafka broker that is serving partition 1 of this topic or that there are networking issues (local storage of broker is ok, but when the consumer is reading the data over the network the data is corrupted in-transit).